# Enabling GKE Backup on regional VPC peering Autopilot Clusters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-kubernetes-engine

We are trying to enable GKE Backup for our Autopilot Clusters, but we are encountering error while trying to run following command (with proper values that is):

```
gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME \
   --project=PROJECT_ID  \
   --region=COMPUTE_REGION \
   --update-addons=BackupRestore=ENABLED
```

But above gives us following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Gce reservation must be enabled for regional VPC peering clusters.
```

And we are not sure what we are missing in regards to configuration. Apparently, we need to use GCE Reservations, but we have no idea how/why all of a sudden.

A bit of information:

- Control Plane version is 1.24.7-gke.900, nodes themselves are at v1.22.13-gke.1000
- Cluster uses shared VPC subnet that is available from another project via VPC Peering (or so my understanding goes of whole setup)
- We are solely using GKE on Autopilot, no other resources being used on this project
- Clusters do have Workload Identity enabled
- Clusters are Regional and on Regular release channel

Trying to find similiar issue or bits of documentation to help us with encountered error were fruitless, so any help is appreciated